# How to keep glasses dry in the rain?

Tags: safety, rain, glasses

Today in the middle of my ride it started raining and I could barely see due to the amount of rain on my glasses.

This is basically what I could see
[image: View with rain on glasses]

I have jokingly talked about using Rain-X on my glasses, but now it's starting to seem like a good idea.

Is there a way to keep this from happening or at least to a minimum?

Comment: Wear contacts? Its just something you learn to deal with.

Comment: Ride backwards.  (You kind of get used to it after awhile.  You do need to slow down and be a bit more cautious, but usually you can see well enough to ride a bike lane or path.  A little trickier if you need to dodge rocks or potholes, or if traffic is bad.)

Comment: Look up hydrophobic coatings used on tools and work apparel. You get them in transparent spray form. It might work

Comment: @c10yas there's no doubt they work to repel water, but will they remain optically clear, will the product damage the lenses and the optical properties of the lens, plus any coatings already on the lens.  Also there's a minor problem of fumes - having the product right by the eyes can cause irritation.  I once superglued my glasses back together, waited ~18 hours, and the fumes were still hideous.

Comment: I doubt it would help. Most prescription glasses with polymer lenses come with good hydrophobic coatings. In my personal experience it did not seem to help very much. In contrast, using bike glasses and contact lenses was find. I can see three reasons for that: (i) the bike glasses are curved such that the wind can blow of droplets, (ii) they are also ventilated on the inside to prevent fogging (iii) distortion by droplets might be more disruptive on optical surfaces (not convincig though)

Comment: Do you ride on the drops or the hoods ?  Sitting up higher will reduce road splatter at face level.

Comment: The image is wrong: It has the rain drops in focus and the biker out of shadow. What you actually see through rainy glasses is a sharp biker plus the out-of-focus rain drops - the raindrops look blurred, not the scene. The problem is, when those rain drops are lit up too much, then the out-of-focus rain drops will be brighter than the sharp details you want to see.

Comment: @cmaster And that's the _actual_ reason for wearing a cap in the rain. It does very little to top water hitting your glasses but it does shield them from a lot of light, massively reducing the glare.

Answer (score 17):

The easy answer is a wide-brim hat or long visor on your helmet. This does work, at least at low speeds. You will have to experiment with options, as nothing like this is sold for this purpose as far as I can tell.

Over about 20kph the length of brim you need gets silly, and by 30kph you need half a metre or so (there are some velomobile owners that do this). But if you're willing to slow down, the brim will work.

I wear glasses, and haven't found a water-shedding coating that works well enough to be worth the hassle. In practice I use a clip-on visor on my bike helmet, extended a little so it's about 10cm in front of my forehead. That keeps the worst of the rain off. Then I ride fast enough that my glasses get wet anyway. But not as wet as without it.

The visor/brim also reduces the amount of water running down my head and into my eyes, especially as that always seems to wash stale sweat out of the helmet pads and that stuff stings. A sweatband or headsock helps there.

Comment: +1 I always wear a cycling cap. It's peak works pretty well for keeping sun or rain off my glasses, and has the advantage that it can be flipped up to give better visibility when needed.

Comment: Even just a regular ball cap will be enough in most situations.  I wear one under my helmet and while it does impact my vision vertically (I have to look up to see traffic lights), it sits low enough to my face and glasses to keep the water out of it.

Comment: I got a 10 buck Trespass synthetic cap, and that solved my commute problems up to medium strength rain.

Comment: Do note that cycling caps have a different brim shape to a baseball cap.  The corners of a baseball cap poke out further, and if curved will drop down and obscure your vision in the sector ~30 degrees either side of center.  A cycling cap is shorter and more rounded and far better for riding, and can be flipped up easily while riding.

Answer (score 7):

The visor certainly helps - mine broke away 6 months ago, but the helmet is undamaged.  Its almost impossible to find replacement brims.

So you might want to think about your technique.  Try riding more defensively:

- Learn to See rather than Look - that's noticing motion through a raindrop or obstruction.
- Position yourself on the road to avoid possible problems.
- Light yourself and your bike up like the Eiffel Tower / Blackpool Tower / Big Glowing thing.  More lights and high-vis the better.

Finally check with your optometrist whether rainx or friends might damage your glasses.  It should be fine on glass lenses, but coatings might suffer.  I wouldn't want to guess on plastic lenses.

If you're getting a new prescription soon, consider getting custom cycling glasses.

Here's a set that put the rain barrier in front of the corrective lens, so the light focussing is less distorted by rain.

[image]

Here's another photo showing from the side.  Notice how the tinted plastic bit comes much further around the head, reducing that eye-drying side-buffeting on a fast downhill.  The corrective lens part can be ground to your prescription by your optometrist.  Depending on model, the front shield may be removable, and may even come with up to 5 or 6 different shades for different riding conditions.  You can even get some models with a safety strap instead of two temples, so they're almost like baby's glasses or slightly like swimming goggles.

[image]

On later thoughts - that foam top band could be both awesome for sweat control, and horrible once it saturates.

I can't wear contacts because they irritate, and I have to wear glasses all the time, so would have to carry normal glasses on a ride too.

Comment: That fixed stare should burn the water off in no time :-)

Comment: @andy256I'm sure Cyclops from Xmen, or Superman don't have this problem.

Comment: The "Learn to See rather than Look" part is key: Once you concentrate on seeing things, your brain can do an amazing job at processing the rain-blurred images. And you might be surprised, you actually can see sharp even with rainy glasses, the real problem is the glare from the headlights of the cars (or other strong lights, traffic lights can be a beast too) that overpowers the dim sharp image.

Comment: I sometimes see a fellow rider with ski goggles on over her glasses. It'd be hot, but it serves the same purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Many cycling gloves are designed with a chamois or microfibre panel on the thumb section. This allows you to wipe glasses with the back of your thumb. It sounds rubbish, but it works really well, even when the gloves are saturated with water. Of course you have to wipe your glasses quite frequently, but in my experience not so much as to impair my riding.

Tip: Use the left hand for the left lens and the right hand for the right lens. Hold the thumb vertical, start at the inside and wipe towards the outside.

Comment: I've always thought that was a nose wiper, a snot panel if you will.

Comment: And I thought it was for sweat.

Comment: I did this almost successfully today, however, rain drops had also got onto the inner side of the lenses. The only way to clear them was by stopping and removing the glasses.

Answer (score 3):

There are sevral options to prevent wet glasses.

1. Do not ride in rain
   This is absolutely foolproof, but it doesn't solve the problem if you want/need to ride.
2. Do not wear glasses in the rain
   You will have clear view, but in heavy rain and/or higher wind this is painful and may be dangerous. They who must wear corrective glasses cannot use that option for sure.
3. Wear helmet with visor
   When riding relatively slow the helmet makes sort of roof over your face protecting your glasses from the rain. Visor gives extra room for protection. (Thanks, @Criggie) In high winds and heavy rain it is useless.
4. Use hydrophobic-coated glasses
   Such (super-)hydrophobic coatings repell water from the surface. Some are polymer-based which are relatively cheap but are vulnereable to scratching and oils. Rare earth ceramics are investigated to sort these drawbacks out, but might be very expensive.
   [Surf sunglasses](http://www.wearsurfglasses.com/Hydrophobiccoatings.html), [Adidas](http://www.adidas.com/Eyewear/content/nz/technology/lens_hydrophobic.asp) glasses are available.
5. Use MotoGP helmet for wet races
   These helmet have double visor with sealed gap. Regradless how you sweat, the visor is still bright without any fogging. The visor is also cvered with set of hydrophobic foils (when worn out, they tear one layer away uncovering new one), or there are two cassettes for hydrophobic tape covering the visor (one cassette with unused tape and second for the used part, when the visor is wetting, racer can roll out new part), or the visor is covered by hydrophobic coating. This option is most expensive, Byt you will have ultimate head protection and comfort in cold weather.

Note that hydrophobic film will create separated water droplet that will easily move on the surface - on the bike they will be blown sideways and drop off. [Superhydrophobic surface](https://youtu.be/FLegmQ8_dHg?t=76) will repel the water droplets as a wall repels tennis balls.

Comment: The helmet itself does little to nothing for rain protection.  Helmets with a visor or brim out the front do cope a bit better.

Comment: How did people in Amsterdam manage to bike to work in the rain without issues when they need glasses? If there's mild nearsightedness or there's a low rate of myopia, then it makes sense. Contact lenses have some risks over glasses.

Comment: @han-lin simply use a hat, hood, or an umbrella. Riding in those cities usually is not at such high speeds that you get hit by rain horizontally. Got to have something that protect one's hair from the rain anyway.

Comment: @gschenk hat, maybe if tightly fitted. hood, umbrella? I've tried a lot of crazy things on bike and riding with umbrella is one of them.

Comment: @Han-Lin by putting up with poor vision and timing rides in between showers. Riding in the rain with glasses always sucked. Fortunately it doesn't rain nearly as often in the Netherlands as the Dutch will have you believe.

Answer (score 2):

In a heavy rain, I just take my glasses off.  Hats or similar don't really protect the glasses enough to be worth the trouble.

Comment: That's not much use if you need the glasses to be able to ride safely

Comment: I wish my vision was decent enough to be able to take them off.

Answer (score 2):

Additional suggestion is to turn your head a little, and often rather than holding the head still and moving your eyes.

As you move your head,  your eyeballs get a "line of sight" around any particular drop, and your brain ends up "gluing" the image together.

Its a subconscious thing, but works well enough when combined with the other physical solutions presented.

Give it a try next time it raining.

Answer (score 2):

As a halfway to wearing a full face helmet, there are helmets with eye-shields like

[image]
or one with less tail:
[image]

Or there are add-ons to your existing helmet which may fit.

[image]

https://bikerumor.com/2015/11/12/rcc15-wide-eyez-flips-any-helmet-into-integrated-visor-mode/ and https://www.wideeyez.com/

Comment: I've seen helmets with TT visors rather often this spring. Seems to be a useful solution.

Comment: I notice they're not sealed to the helmet - there's an airgap either for ventilation or possibly for flexing movement.

Comment: You know, those visors could perhaps be treated with a spray on hydrophobic coating.

Answer (score 2):

The vision it mostly interfered by raindrops sticking on the glass when the glass between raindrops is still dry. This happens in the beginning of the rain.

It helps to sweep the glass with the finger, so that all surface becomes equally wet and drops find they way down faster. It is not the same as the dry glass in good weather but the vision improves.

Comment: Agreed - If its raining, wearing gloves with full fingers makes this easier.  Half-fingered gloves don't dry as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have a 10 mile commute to work and then back again, I’ve found that polishing your glasses with ( I use Mr Sheen Multi Surface Polish ) before setting off helps a little with repelling the rain and certainly helps when you have to stop and wipe your glasses, my glasses are glass and I’ve had no problems with it affecting the glass.

Comment: I'd be very worried about that destroying the coatings on the lenses.

Comment: My glasses have a UV darkening coating that is breaking down from age and/or RainX treatment.  I'm not sure which is most to blame.

Comment: @Criggie Yeah but Rain-X isn't furniture polish.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this problem & considering getting a full motorbike helmet with the water repellant on visor as nothing else seems to help

Comment: So to clarify, you're riding a bicycle in the rain, while wearing glasses, and contemplating a full-face motorbike helmet to keep your eyewear dry?  Seems like a valid answer to me.

Comment: I ride all year in all weather conditions (even once during a tornado — oops). Rain on my glasses (or goggles in winter) is solvable by wiping them with gloves (as mentioned in another answer here), even in hot summer rain, I'll wear gloves if I'm wearing glasses. Either that or wear contacts.

Comment: This would be more of a useful answer if you’d tried using a moto helmet and could tell us some pros and cons. Otherwise it’s just saying you haven’t found an answer yet

Comment: Every time I've heard of somebody riding a bicycle wearing a motorcycle helmet, they've said that it was unbearably hot and heavy. They don't say the same about riding a motorbike because that involves much less physical effort and has a different seating position. Heck, cyclists don't even wear full-face downhill mountain-biking helmets unless they're downhill mountain-biking -- and for the same reason.

Comment: @IanMacDonald do please join the [chat] I'm curious to know more about your tornado ride, but it wouldn't be a good fit for the normal Q&A question format.

Comment: @Criggie He wanted the Strava KOM.  :-D  It's been known to happen.  If you take the time (and if you can any more - thanks Strava...), you'll find one of the top times on this [Strava segment](https://www.strava.com/segments/7012249) was set during a hurricane with one heckuva tailwind - IIRC it was in the 2011-2012 time frame.  And no, it's not my time - I just thought about going out.  I didn't actually do it, but I do remember seeing someone's effort the next day.