# How to deal with fog, condensing on the outside of glasses?

Tags: weather, glasses

I had a particularly foggy commute both ways today.  I was having to wipe the glasses lenses every 10-20 seconds as traffic permitted to maintain some semblance of visibility.

I already wear a cap with a brim/peak/visor under my helmet, but the fog is light enough to flow under with air-flow - its not like rain that would fall more downward.

Short of "wipe lots" what can be done to keep fog from depositing on glasses?

[image]

Comment: Pointing out this is not a dupe of  "glasses fog up in cold weather" questions which tends to deposit steam on the inside (eyeball side)   This question is like rain on the lenses, but its too light to run down under gravity.

Comment: You could try something like rain x on the lens to see if it makes the water run down the lens rather than collecting as a fine film. I've never tried it, so I'm not sure how well it would work.

Comment: The main reason why one day I switched to contact lenses!

Comment: I tried the Muc-Off anti fog (which is generally well reviewed) and found it rather lacking.

Comment: @carel many cyclists still wear glasses without prescription, shaded or clear, to protect their eyes so the question could still be relevant to contact lens users

Comment: This question certainly seems relevant, https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/42979/how-to-keep-glasses-dry-in-the-rain?rq=1

Comment: Caps don't much stop rain getting on your glasses; rather, they shade the lenses to cut down on glare from the bright sky or street lighting bouncing around in the raindrops. Fog is rather different because the droplets on your lenses are much smaller and coat much more of the lens.

Comment: @Swifty yes its a similar question, but fog has some different characteristics.  Like, it builds up steadily, and flows upward against gravity due to air currents.

Comment: Nitpick: fog is already liquid (micro droplets suspended in air), so it doesn't condense. I would rather says coalesces. Body moisture/perspiration do condense on glasses.

Comment: I've got some rain-x (I use it on my phone screen). I could belive it would work when going fast but not at low speeds - it needs airflow to make the droplets run. It might still be useful - the droplets might run down from simply tapping the frame rather than wiping. I'd test but those conditions are rare and as I don't need prescription glasses I can just not wear anything over my eyes in fog

Comment: @Swifty : This was meant for those wearing optical glasses behind or attached to cycling shades.

Comment: @DavidRicherby : Also visors impede the airflow behind the cycling glasses and increase humidity. Those glasses are designed to promote ventilation of the lens. Blocking the ventilation may cause even more moisture to fog up the lens. If you observe pro riders on a rainy stage of a race, those wearing glasses are only few.

Comment: @carel You're right, but this question is specific to fog depositing on the outside of the glasses.  Will be trying the rain-X on monday.

Comment: @Criggie I've tweaked the title as people seem to be missing a key point.  Consider it a suggestion and feel free to roll back

Comment: @AndyP on the inside or outside? (And which was it meant for?)

Comment: @ChrisH I tried to do the outsides of some clear lenses for a cold/damp 24hr MTB race.  Whether I used too much, too little, or was over vigorous wiping off excess I don't know, but have tried 3 times now and given up

Comment: @ChrisH three comments: (1) a hydrophobic coating (increases contact angle) might lead to drops aggregating in larger drops (less interface area, increased drop mobility). Larger drops are less of an issue. (2) are there very hydrophilic surfectants for glasses? If the fog would not deposit droplets but join a film one might gain a little distortion rather than scattering. Gelatine or saliva might do. Swimmers used to do this. (3) The new title is confusing for reason L.Dutch gave. The drops would rather deposit than condense. Fogging in saturated air would be a different (older) question.

Comment: @gschenk yes, I think anti fog solutions for swimming goggles are hydrophilic so a film condenses. Hydrophobic coatings, like rain-x should make for fewer, bigger drops which may blow off. I completely agree with you that the droplets are collecting rather than condensing, but I think I tried to make the smallest edit I could to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Dishwashing liquid, cheapest and best way to lose that extra liquid.

If you have a yellowish lens they make a difference with seeing contrasting low light.

Answer (score 0):

For outdoor sports, when I wear googles or lenses, I spit on the interior of my lenses and spread a thin layer to prevent condensation.

A tidier option would be to buy an anti-fog spray at the local sport or ski shop and apply.

Comment: That's a sensible answer to the linked question, but not to this one, which is specific to the outside

Comment: Chris is right - this question is about fog that is suspended in the air like baby raindrops, but too light to fall.  It collects on the front of the lenses because of forward movement, rather than condensing.

Comment: The same might help though. If the contact angle is small enough condensed and deposited droplets alike would flow into each other. Forming a water film that doesn't scatters, although distorts, images.

Answer (score 0):

I have used mild dishwashing liquid with some success. Put on neat, then rinse off with warm water, drying with kleenex tissue, but one without aloe vera as this will smear the lens. Can also use clear fitover safety glasses from a hardware store.

Edit. I use the clear fitovers in foggy conditions and they seem to work. But you could also use the dishwashing liquid method as well.

Comment: How would an extra layer of safety glasses help with fog settling on glasses ?

Answer (score 0):

for me, when my glasses become more of a hazard than a benefit, I take them off.  In the conditions described in the question I don't think there is anything you can do to keep your lenses perfectly clear.

Comment: Fair point - I remember riding 30 years ago when my vision wasn't as bad, and could see well enough without any glasses.  Now I need my glasses for everything, so this is no longer an option.

Comment: Ah.  Prescription lenses...  The only answer I can think of is contact lenses.

Comment: It's easy enough to check, though, whether you see more with or without glasses. So, definitely worth trying to just take them off, see if that's an improvement, and ride on with the better alternative. The greatest danger of fog on glasses is the glare of lights that can easily make stuff like a construction hole totally invisible. Unless you have quite seriously impaired vision, you won't suffer from glare as much with your naked eyes as with glasses.